# How to import a dumb file to Azure DB on mySQL Server, the dump resides in the blob. How can I dynamically access the blob file

Tags: mysql, powershell, azure-blob-storage

My power shell code, downloads the dump file from azure storage to my local drive. 
  `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $storagecontainername -Blob $backupfilename -Destination $restorefilename`

Import happens using the dump file in the local drive.
`get-content $restorefilename | &"$mysqlpath" -h $servername -u $username -p $password $database`

I am looking to replace  this `$restorefilename` with the blob file directly.

Comment: why do you want to read blob file directly? In azure powershell, no such cmdlet. It always download the blob file first, then use it.  And what is the access to the blob, private or public? If you consider this, I think you can use powershell to call .net methods for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in cmdlet for this.

You can use some .net method in powershell to directly download the blob files as string.

Note: if the blob storage is public, you can just directly use it's url. if the blob storage is private, you should generate a SAS token for the blob.

sample code as below for a public blob:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadString("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/f22/t1.txt")
```

Test result as below:

[image]

so in your case, you can write something like below:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$restorefilename = $client.DownloadString("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/f22/t1.txt")
$restorefilename | &"$mysqlpath" -h $servername -u $username -p $password $database
```

And if your blob is private, you can follow the screenshot below to generate a sas url for downloading:

[image]

Comment: This is not working when downloading large files (9.5 GB. Below is the exception.  `Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The message length limit was exceeded"
At line:2 char:1
+ $restorefilename = $client.DownloadString("https://storageaccountname ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException`

Comment: @kottis, I'm sorry, as of now, I have no idea if the file is very large. And I also research a lot, most of people suggest download it first to your local file, then read it just like you did before.

Comment: I am downloading the file at the moment. Below is the code and getting exception here as well. Is this also due to the large file data or you see any issue with the code. `$restorefilename = "C:\tmp\tdsclogdb_2232019_926.sql"
$mysqlpath = "C:\tools\mysql\current\bin\mysql.exe"
get-content $restorefilename|&"$mysqlpath" -h $servername -u $username -p  -$database`
`Program 'mysql.exe' failed to run: capacity was less than the current size.
Parameter name: requiredLengthAt line:3 char:30
+ ... orefilename|&"$mysqlpath" -h $servername ...

Comment: @kottis, can you just try executing the command "get-content $restorefilename", to see if it works fine or throw some errors?

Comment: Yes `get-content` works fine. I think the issue is with the mysql.exe